# send data back from jsp iterator to struts action class

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I have used the iterator tags to display the data in the jsp.

```xml
<s:iterator value="prodAL" status="id">
    <tr>
    <td><s:property value="PName"/></td>
    <td><s:property value="model"/></td>
    <td><s:property value="price"/></td>
    <td><s:property value="quantity"/></td>
    <td><s:property value="status"/></td>
    </tr>
</s:iterator
```

how do i implement a button(or other clickable interface element) so that when it is clicked,only the contents of that particular row should be passed to another jsp or action class where the contents can be edited.

Comment: As it is, it's a bit too broad...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a link to each row, and include on the query string all the information you want to send for that row.

Something like:

```
<td><a href="...your address...?status=<s:property value="status"/>&model=<s:property value="status"/>&...</td>
```

Comment: If you use the struts anchor tag (s:a) the url can be generated in a bit more readable way (along with the nested s:param tags): https://struts.apache.org/docs/a.html

Answer (score 2):

You must always pass through actions, and from actions dispatching JSPs. Never jump from one JSP to another JSP directly.

That said, if you want to draw a list of products, select one of them, land on another page and editing it, the flow is:

- **Action One**: load and expose a `List<Product>` through a getter;
- **JSP One**: iterates the list of products inside a `<form>` that is targeting **Action Two**; use an `<s:hidden />`, an `<s:checkbox/>` or whatever in conjunction with a button (if you want one button for each row, use the hidden attribute, if you want a single edit button in the whole page then use the checkboxes) to send the Product**ID** to **Action Two**
- **Action Two**: receive through a setter the ProductID, use it to load the Product, expose the Product through a getter, render **JSP Two**
- **JSP Two**: expose Product attributes through `<s:textfield />`, use `<s:hidden />` for ProductID.